# CSS/HTML: Inputfield in the middle of the floated element

Tags: html, css

I have this right now:

http://jsfiddle.net/Rf8gy/
And this is how I want it:

[image]

If you see in the fiddle, the input field is at top. I want it be like the middle of the floated element on the left. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easier way is to add a top margin to the input:

```
#statusUpdate {
    margin-top:10px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add this line in your css:

```
#smartStatus_writer input{
    margin-top: 11px;
}
```